# Excel custom transpose cell

Tags: excel, transpose

I have some data with format like this

[image]

i want to transform the data look to this order

[image]

is there a way to do this?

i still not found any solution to this problem, the closes i find is transpose but it will not transform the data the way i wanted it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look for `unpivot` methods. This can be done easily in Power Query. Requires extra coding if you want the Patient ID's to only be present once.

Comment: This help me a lot, using your advice to check unpivot  and it works great. Thanks for your great advice - Hake